# How can I correct the following perl program to check directory existence

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$path = <STDIN>;

if (-e $path) {
    print "present";
}
else {
    print "Not present";
}
```

Why is it always printing "Not present"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the newline character from your variable using [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
$path = <STDIN>;
chomp $path;
```

Answer (score 1):

- You forgot to check for EOF.
- You forgot to remove the trailing newline.
- You say the directory doesn't exists when you are unable to check if it exists or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

defined( my $path = <STDIN> );
   or exit;

if (-e $path) {
    print "Present";
}
elsif ($!{ENOENT}) {
    print "Not present";
}
else {
    die("stat: $!");
}
```

Finally, it's probably wrong to use `-e` in the first place. It's always a symptom of a bug in your code. Don't check if a file exists before trying to open it; just try to open it. Don't check if a directory exists before trying to create it; just try to create it.